# python add users input to an empty list using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

so I want to add users input to an empty list using this code

```
no_of_num=int(input('enter the number of numbers you would like to add\n='))#this will store the number of numbers to be added 
list_of_num=[]#this list will store the number to be added
for i in range(0,no_of_num):#we will ask them for the input
    num=int(input('enter the number\n='))
    list_of_num.append(num)#this will keep adding the numbers to the list
result=sum_of_num(num)
```

but when I try running this code it just add the last number that the user inputs to the list

Comment: why are you adding the running number of your range to your list, not the number that was put in by the user ?

Comment: sorry i didnt understand

Comment: you are adding `i`  not `num`

Comment: i tried that too but it didnt  work so i tried num

Answer (score 1):

@Ram Pandey is right add `num` instead if `i` try this, it works

```
for i in range(0,no_of_num):
    num=int(input('enter the number\n='))
    list_of_num.append(num)
print(sum(list_of_num))
```